# HTTP 404 on Ajax call when using WebClient.DownloadString(url) from Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am making a typical ajax call within a javascript function:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
url: '@Url.Content("~/Incident/LookUpStudent")',
            data: { userInput: userInputStudentLDN },
            success: function (result) { //doing stuff here}
});
```

This call goes to this method in the controller:

```
    public string LookUpStudent(string userInput)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput)) { return "Student not found. Please try again."; }

         try
        {
           var fetchedData = new WebClient().DownloadString(JSONUrl); //download the data from the URL
        }

        //return statement and other stuff here
    }
```

I simplified my LookUpStudent Method but basically, as I step through the code and get to this part where I call

```
new WebClient().DownloadString(JSONUrl);
```

My current page immediately gets a 404 error, even though the new WebClient().DownloadString(JSONUrl); call is successful. *fetchedData* just allows me to do some validation before I return  a string from the ajax method.

Here is the 404 error:

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Incident/Action
```

I don't now why this adds "Action" to the end of the url..
Why does this cause a 404 error and how can I fix this?

**Edit 1 based on Kosala W answer:**

```
            var req = { userInput: userInputStudentLDN };
        $.get('@Url.Content("~/Incident/LookUpStudent")', { userInput: req }, function (result) {
            //result is your response from the controller
        });
```

Comment: What is the value of `JSONUrl`?

Comment: What sort of string output are you expecting from `LookUpStudent`?

Comment: I noticed an obvious spelling mistake in your URL.  Shouldn't  `Incident/LookUpStudente` be `Incident/LookUpStudent` ?

Comment: @KosalaW Whatever I decide to output, and it works fine. It just the very second I call var fetchedData = new WebClient().DownloadString(JSONUrl); I get a 404 error even though fetchedData is successfully filled

Comment: @KosalaW yes that spelling mistake is correct in my actual code, I must have made that mistake when posting this question here. sorry, i'll edit that

Comment: How you are calling `LookupStudent` is fairly irrelevant if it is being called successfully. The problem is when your C# code calls `JSONUrl`. You need to give us more details of that instead, especially what are the expected and actual values of it as @miparnisari said. It sounds like you are getting one error in the download which is triggering or being passed down to the result of `LookupStudent`.

Comment: @Rhumborl yeah, you are right. The value of JSONUrl is (for example): "http://directory.osu.edu/fpjson.php?name_n=http://directory.osu.edu/fpjson.php?name_n=smith.8020"

Comment: @Michael: Have a look at my answer and ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As embarrassing as it is, this issue was caused by having a `<button>` inside a @Html.BeginForm('Action', 'Incident').

The button was submitting the form by default (Even though I did not explicitly set type="submit").
At the same time, I was also running an Ajax statement from javascript on the button's click event.

Therefore, the ajax call would be made as well as a post to a non-existent action-result called 'Action'.

Thank you for everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery like this.

```
 var req = { term: document.getElementById("Term").value, classNum: document.getElementById("ClassNumber").value };
        $.get("/Incident/LookUpStudent", { userInput: req }, function (result) {
           //result is your response from the controller
        });
```

Change your controller like below.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult LookUpStudent(object userInput)
    {       
        try
        {
            if (userInput == null) 
            { 
                throw new Exception("Student not found. Please try again.");
            }
            var fetchedData = new WebClient().DownloadString(JSONUrl); //download the data from the URL
            return Json(fetchedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: First of all I screwed up the Ajax part of my Original Post, I have edited since. But I still tried implementing the ajax call how you have it, except now the parameter wont come through to the controller. All I get is null. I will edit My OP with what my ajax statement looks like

Comment: @Michael Why you are not getting the parameter value may be a serialisation issue. You can either change the parameter to a string from jquery side or you can change your controller to accept `object` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `type` in there:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Incident/LookUpStudent")',
            data: { term: document.getElementById("Term").value, classNum: document.getElementById("ClassNumber").value},
            success: function (result) { //doing stuff here}
});
```

Comment: `GET` is the default for `$.ajax`, so not required.

Comment: I have done this, And it makes no difference, as @Rhumborl states.